# How can I fix the 'reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id' error in my jQuery interface?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that we have already discussed this problem a lot, but these solutions do not suit me and I cannot understand why the error occurs
VM12505 recaptcha__en.js:201 not intercepted (in promise) Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or identifier
at VM12505 recaptcha__en.js:201:504
with onloadcallback (template_e1fea8b24e0871ae01c20a8dc3de3052_v1.js?1685481313306076:110:14)

```
var onloadCallback = function () {
  let mysitekey = 'key';

  grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
    'sitekey': 'key',
    'callback': onRecaptchaSuccess,
    'expired-callback': onRecaptchaExpired,
    'timeout': 120000
  });

  grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
    'sitekey': 'key',
    'callback': onRecaptchaSuccess2,
    'expired-callback': onRecaptchaExpired,
    'timeout': 120000
  });
  grecaptcha.render('recaptcha3', {
    'sitekey': 'key',
    'callback': onRecaptchaSuccess3,
    'expired-callback': onRecaptchaExpired,
    'timeout': 120000,
  });
};

var isRecaptchaChecked = false; // Флаг для отслеживания отмеченности reCAPTCHA

function onRecaptchaSuccess(response) {
  // Действия при успешной проверке reCAPTCHA
  console.log('reCAPTCHA успешно пройдена1.');
  console.log('Ответ:', response);
  isRecaptchaChecked = true; // Устанавливаем флаг в true
}

function onRecaptchaSuccess2(response) {
  // Действия при успешной проверке reCAPTCHA
  console.log('reCAPTCHA успешно пройдена2.');
  console.log('Ответ:', response);
  isRecaptchaChecked = true; // Устанавливаем флаг в true
}
function onRecaptchaSuccess3(response) {
  // Действия при успешной проверке reCAPTCHA
  console.log('reCAPTCHA успешно пройдена3.');
  console.log('Ответ:', response);
  isRecaptchaChecked = true; // Устанавливаем флаг в true
}

function onRecaptchaExpired() {
  // Действия при истечении срока действия отклика на reCAPTCHA
  console.log('Срок действия reCAPTCHA истек.');
  isRecaptchaChecked = false; // Устанавливаем флаг в false
}
```

I offered to change the code, but nothing came out, so I issued a digitization of VM12505 recaptcha__en.js:201 not intercepted (in the promise) Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or identifier
at VM12505 recaptcha__en.js:201:504
with onloadcallback (template_e1fea8b24e0871ae01c20a8dc3de3052_v1.js?1685481313306076:110:14)

Comment: Do you have html elements with the ids of recaptcha1, recaptcha2 and recaptcha3?

Comment: Yes of course)) the forms that are on the main page they have a captcha and the forms on the other page do not show a captcha